# How to build a diagram Charts.ChartType.COMBO according to the settings?

Tags: userscripts

I am trying to create a combo chart in sheet embedded script.
The problem is that the build doesn't match the settings.
For example, I specify the type "area", and "bars" are built

How to build a diagram according to the settings?

My current code and the result are given below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F7-pugxgWhfEhPouqkLA5kp-Sfv4KXUHmaBbeEcbAEw/edit#gid=0

function myTest() {

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1F7-pugxgWhfEhPouqkLA5kp-Sfv4KXUHmaBbeEcbAEw").getSheetByName('Лист1');
```

var chart = sheet.newChart()

```
   .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true) 
   .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)
   .addRange(sheet.getRange('A2:D5'))

     .setOption('series', {
                     0:{type: "area"},
                     1:{type: "bars"},
                     2:{type: "line"}
                        })

   .setPosition(7, 2, 0, 0)

   .build();
```

sheet.insertChart(chart);
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5DTC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also have a working code that allows you to build a combo chart, but in a different method:

```
function myTest() {
var data = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "month")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "A")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "B")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "C")
      
    .addRow(["Feb", 10, 5,100])
    .addRow(["Mar", 300, 3,200])
    .addRow(["Apr", 100, 5,150])
      .build();

  
  
  var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()
      .setDataTable(data)
  
        .setOption('series', {
          0: {type: 'area', dataLabel: 'value'},
          1: {type: 'bars',dataLabel: 'value'},
          2: {type: 'line',dataLabel: 'value', dataLabel: 'value', curveType: 'function'},
          })
      .setRange(0, 100)
      .setTitle('Название таблицы '+d)
      .build();
}
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trTH4.png)

What am I doing wrong in the first case?